# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar la lista de ramas remotas?

Tags: git, ramas-git

Hay veces en que uno va trabajando en distintas ramas de Git y, ya sea porque usa git flow o cualquier otro motivo, esas ramas acaban siendo *mergeadas* en develop o master.

Pasa el tiempo y en el repositorio local se acumulan las ramas específicas que se han ido creando y *mergeando*.

En el repositorio remoto, pongamos que en GitLab, cada vez que tenemos que integrar alguna de estas ramas realizamos un *merge request* (o un *pull request* en GitHub). Cuando se junta la rama, podemos indicar que se elimine, de modo que en remoto el listado de ramas siempre es pequeño: *master*, *develop* y aquellas en las que se esté trabajando.

El problema surge en local, donde se van acumulando referencias a ramas remotas que ya *murieron* hace tiempo.

Así pues, la duda es: **¿Cómo puedo actualizar la lista de ramas remotas?**

Comment: si estás usando `git flow` debieras poder hacer `git hf update` y sincronizar las ramas del remoto con las locales, incluyendo borrar las locales que no existen en el remoto.

Comment: @amenadiel lo tendré en cuenta, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplemente debes hacer:

```
git remote update origin --prune
```

Una vez lo hayas hecho, ya no tendrás referencia a todas aquellas que ya se eliminaron. Para ver el listado completo debes hacer:

```
git branch -a
```

Información sacada de [When does git refresh the list of remote branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358502/1983854)

Comment: Me ha venido genia! +1x2!

Comment: Para que funciona el prune?

Comment: @Carlost "prune" en inglés es _podar_. Por tanto, lo que hace es podar, eliminar las ramas que no se usan

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar:

```
git remote update origin
```

y con

```
git branch --all
```

puedes visualizar las ramas ya actualizadas