# Ocultar las ramas mergeadas y cerradas de Git en Sourcetree

Tags: git, ramas-git, sourcetree

Recientemente hice una migración de Mercurial a Git en Bitbucket, sin problemas, y continué trabajando como hacía con Sourcetree (no me siento cómoda trabajando con consola, lo siento). Y me encuentro con el siguiente problema: Hago una rama, trabajo en ella, una vez finalizado el trabajo hago commit y push, después pull request, en el que mergeo y cierro la rama, me voy a master, hago pull (no me dice lo que me va a bajar y en mercurial sí que me avisaba), me baja los cambios a master, me cambio a master, pero la rama que ya está mergeada y cerrada sigue apareciendo en el visor lateral de la izq, cosa que no pasaba con Mercurial, pues en Options tiene un check que permite ocultar las ramas ya cerradas. ¿No existe algo similar para Git? ¿Se van a quedar por siempre mis ramas cerradas en el visor lateral? ¿Hay algo que se pueda hacer? Adjunto imágenes.

Incluso si le doy al menú contextual sobre la rama sigue apareciendo la opción de merge y de pull request.

Lo que me gustaría es que la rama desapareciera del visor de la izquierda pero no del gráfico, como pasaba cuando trabajaba con mercurial. ¿Es posible esto?

Gracias de antemano

[image: Vista de la rama mergeada y cerrada y del visor lateral]

[image: Menú contextual sobre la rama]

Comment: Hola de nuevo. He seguido indagando y he hecho lo que comenta el usuario fedorqui en el hilo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155487/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-actualizar-la-lista-de-ramas-remotas?rq=1. Pero no me ha funcionado, eso lo que hace es eliminar la rama del remoto pero sigue estando en la lista de ramas de mi local. Sigo buscando solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, no hay nada de malo en usar una UI.. y que nadie te diga lo contrario..

Por otro lado no soy un experto en Sourcetree pero he trabajado con compañeros que la usan así que veamos si puedo ayudarte.

En consola sería:

```
git fetch -p origin HEAD
```

`-p` elimina las ramas del remoto que se hayan borrado ya.

Luego puedes lanzar algo así para borrar todas las ramas que están merged

```
git branch --merged | grep -v '^*' | grep -v 'master' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

Dicho esto. Intentemos hacerlo con sourcetree, por lo que entiendo, al hacer un `fetch` y hacer click en `prune tracking branches` esto borrará de tu pc las ramas remotas que se hayan borrado. Pero al parecer no hay una forma de borrar las ramas clonadas, así que tendrás que hacerlo a mano por lo poco que veo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Al final lo he conseguido hacer en sourcetree haciendo fetch y luego sobre la rama con botón derecho y delete.